# Almost Simultaneous HTTPServletRequests

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

Is it possible to reject a request to my servlet or not respond to it? Say if I recieve 2 requests within 100 ms on the same thread, can I ignore the second one completely? Or is it possible to abort the 1st request and only handle the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reject subsequent requests, you would need to record the time of the first request you are willing to process then (return a bad response, not respond etc) for any request within a period of the first.
eg:

```
   private static final Object LOCK_OBJECT = new Object();
   private static long lastAokTime;
   private static final long MIN_REQUEST_TIME_MILLIS = 100L;

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   {
      synchronized(LOCK_OBJECT) {
         final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
         if (lastAokTime == 0 || (now - lastAokTime < MIN_REQUEST_TIME_MILLIS)) {

            // reject the request
            response.setStatus(500); // perhaps?
            return;            
         } else {
            lastAokTime = now; 
         }

         // carry on and process request
      }
   }
```

Threading is interesting, but do you really want it per-thread or do you want it as a global property (app servers do quite a bit of thread work behind the scenes to help you)?  The above sample is global, but you could replace the LOCK_OBJECT with a ThreadLocal object if you want to lock it to a thread.

Good luck.